# What do priority and parallelism value mean in Azure Data Lakes (Hadoop)?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-data-lake, u-sql

In other words, what does a parallelism value of 5 and a priority value of 1000 mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They impact how and when your job can run. Priority determines in which order a job can run in relation to other queued jobs, parallelism sets how many parallel processes are started for it (more means it runs faster but costs more)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-manage-use-portal

**Priority**

> Lower number has higher priority. If two jobs are both queued, the one with lower priority runs first

The default value is 1000 for this.

**Parallelism**

> Max number of compute processes that can happen at the same time. Increasing this number can improve performance but can also increase cost.